# How can I scroll using my fingers when my iPad is being used as Sidecar?

Tags: macos, ipad, sidecar

I can't scroll using finger touches. I can only scroll using my Mac's trackpad.

Seeing from their [own guides](https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/use-ipad-as-a-second-display-for-mac-ipad2b1aa3be/ipados), it should be allowed:

> Use standard gestures on iPad: Use your fingers to tap, touch and hold, swipe, scroll, and zoom.

Is my understanding of the feature correct? Can anyone get this to work?

Does anyone if there's something else required to enable touches during Sidecar?

Answer (score 5):

Scroll with two fingers on the iPad screen, like you do on a trackpad, with your fingers within the area to be scrolled.

Comment: ‍♂️ and is there a way to select/tap using the iPad?